# How to re-ask this question?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, asking-questions

I asked a question [PHP & SQL Server - field names truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849236/php-sql-server-field-names-truncated) a little while ago and even put a bounty on it.  I received an answer that was upvoted quite a bit but I didn't have a chance at the time to confirm it.  I accepted the answer and gave the user the bounty.

Today, I did some testing to verify the answer and found that it's not correct in my particular situation.

I considered removing my acceptance to the answer and editing the question to add additional information, but I am afraid that users may be misled into thinking that the question has been answered since the bounty has been awarded.  I have added a comment to the accepted answer for now.

How do I re-ask this question to solicit for more correct answers?

Comment: Meh. Just unaccept and leave a polite comment explaining why.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You

1. unaccept the answer
2. leave a comment to let the answerer know that it didn't work
3. maybe edit something into the question on why that approach didn't work and results
4. then set a new bounty on the question and pray.